# How to test genexus site using JMeter, receiving error "Not in GZIP format"

Tags: java, jmeter, gzip, genexus

I'm trying to make a test for my genexus web application (generates Java) with JMeter, but I'm getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format 
  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source) 
  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream. (Unknown Source) 
  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream. (Unknown Source) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.readResponse(HTTPJavaImpl.java:269) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:516) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Apparently, it's a known error according to genexus wiki: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Stress+Test+Tips,

However, I still want to know if there is a workaround to make it work, otherwise I can't use JMeter to test my application.

I also saw this post: [How do I avoid the "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format" error while using JMeter 2.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026273/how-do-i-avoid-the-java-util-zip-zipexception-not-in-gzip-format-error-while)
and tried unchecking the "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" option in the 'HTTP Requests Defaults' and change the 'HTTP sampler settings' to 'Java', but I'm still getting the error.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is it you're trying to unzip? Is it a single zipped file or an archive with multiple files? If it's an archive, you can't use GZip, because it's used for zipping single files. You should use [`java.util.zip.ZipFile`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920684/java-extracting-zip-file-with-multiple-subdirectories) instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. It is a single file yes, is an excel. What the web panel does is let you chose an excel file and then, when you press 'ok', it extracts information from it to insert it in the db. The thing is that at the same time it has a progress bar, im not sure if that is part of the problem, having a procedure processing the excel and at the same time the web panel keeps changing with the progress bar.

Comment: I must add that it is while simulating this 'ok' button that im getting this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid the "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format" error while using JMeter 2.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026273/how-do-i-avoid-the-java-util-zip-zipexception-not-in-gzip-format-error-while)

Comment: I added a section about Genexus in your linked Stack Overflow Post.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I honestly don't know what I ended up doing, but I no longer work in the company and haven't used genexus for over a year,  I should have said here what I did. I probably didn't do anything and didn't test that part  