# Retrieve a file from a sobfolder in a zip

Tags: java, inputstream, zip

I have a zip file structure.

```
MyZip.zip
    folder_1
        folder_1_1
            file_1_1_1
            file_1_1_2
        folder_1_2
            file_1_2_1
            file_1_2_2
    folder_2
        folder_2_1
            folder_2_1_1
                needed_file   //This is the file I need to read.
```

So, I need to read file - `needed_file` from `folder_2_1_1` folder, which is inside of `folder_2_1`, and so on.

This is [how to unzip all data from a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920684/java-extracting-zip-file-with-multiple-subdirectories). I do not need to unzip the archive. My question, is it possible to retrieve the file I need without unzipping the whole archive.

I tried

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry("folder_2");
```

But I did not find a way how to manipulate `zipEntry` as a directory.

Comment: Try with `path/to/your/filename` as entry.

Comment: This may interest you http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-zip/zipfile.html

Comment: Found my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32179328/4587961. 

`while (entries.hasNext()) { ZipEntry ze = entries.next(); if (zp.getName().equals(name_with_folder)) {readData(zp);} }`